# How to change props of another component in parent component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

I have created a widget (child component if you will) that displays images that I have pushed to NPM to use in another (parent component if you will) component, which is a completely new project. How can I change the props value of this child component from the parent component given my circumstances with using NPM? I would like to change the number of images displayed from 5 to 10.

The child component clearly works within the parent component and I have already tried to change the prop value underneath where I defined the component.

Parent component ("Widget" is the child component and is an arbitrary name and is working until I try to change the props):

```
<template>
  <Widget></Widget>
</template>

<script>
import Widget from "widget";
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    Widget: {
      props: {
        perPage: {
          type: Number,
          default: 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Child component that is published on NPM:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Widget',
  props: {
    perPage: {
      type: Number,
      default: 5
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I would like to change the "perPage" "default" from 5 to 10 as displayed in the code above. This code provided should be sufficient to solve this issue, but if more code is necessary, I can definitely provide that too. Thanks!

Just want to reiterate that the child component from NPM is in proper working form in the parent component (which is a completely new project) until I attempt to change the prop values.

Comment: I can't see how do you pass the props from parent to child, as i can see it will work just with the default values since no value is passed from parent to child

Comment: can you elaborate? sorry, I am new to vue

Comment: for sure, i will edit my answer

Comment: @Plastic Just realized your answer is exactly my code haha. With that being said, it still doesn't work - the app is actually giving me a blank screen with this. Do you think because this using NPM and another project/app, it is not working as stated in the vue.js docs?

Comment: this link almost solves it... https://alligator.io/vuejs/intro-to-component-props/

Comment: I didn't realize you had sintactic typo on your code, my fault, as your link suggest I edited my answer properly, give it a try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass the props through the widget template

as you can read into the [vue.js docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props) if you want to pass some information dinamically from parent to child the best way by the template, so in your app template you will pass data through the widget tag

```
<template>
  <Widget :perPage ="perPage"></Widget>
</template>

<script>
import Widget from './Widget.vue'; //assuming they are in the same folder

export default {
  components: {
     Widget
  },
  data() {
     return {
        perPage: 5
     }
  }
}
</script>

//Widget.vue
<template>
  <p>Per Page: {{perPage}}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Widget',
    props: [
      'perPage'
    ]
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I would like for the props in the child component to remain at 5 if that is possible